# Regular expression with decimal point

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate a textbox with a regular expression...

```
  regex expression=(\d{0,4})?([\.]{1})?(\d{0,2})
```

I am having a problem with the decimal point. the decimal point is optional. the regex should validate for only one decimal point.

```
    example 1.00 ,23.22 , .65 is valid
    1..  or  23.. is invalid.
```

Any suggestions for improving my regex??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one : `^\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,2})?$`

It should match :

```
1
200
9999
12.35
522.4
```

But not :

```
1000000
65.
.65
10.326
65..12
```

**Edit :**

If you want to match 65. or 9999. use this one instead (see comments) :

```
^\d{1,4}(\.(\d{1,2})?)?$
```

Comment: That will exclude `9999.` which may or may not be desired but that's easy to fix if necessary.

Comment: hmm it shouldn't exclude 9999 :| since it allows from 1 to 4 decimals

Comment: `9999` will get through but `9999.` (note the final `.`) won't.

Comment: Yes I didn't see the dot, but it is on purpse not to match (or should it be matched ?)

Comment: I don't know if they want to match `9999.` or not, I'm just pointing out a possible edge case. Switching `\d{1,2}` to `\d{0,2}` would be another option if you didn't want more groups.

Comment: ^\d{1,4}(\.(\d{1,2})?)?$ this is working great.. one more thing .65 should be valid

Comment: :o if that would be valid too youcan just change \d{1,4} to \d{0,4} :|

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Application Logic Instead

While you could certainly construct a regular expression for this, it seems simpler to check for a data type or class, or simply scan your input for decimals and then count them. For example, using Ruby:

- Check that value is a float or integer.

  ```rb
  # Literal value is a float, so it belongs to the Float class.
  value = 1.00
  value.class == Fixnum or value.class == Float
  => true

  # Literal value is an integer, so it belongs to the Fixnum class.
  value = 23
  value.class == Fixnum or value.class == Float
  => true
  ```
- Count decimals and make sure there's no more than one.

  ```rb
  # Literal value is a float. When cast as a string and scanned,
  # only one decimal should be found.
  value = 23.22
  value.to_s.scan(/\./).count <= 1
  => true

  # The only way this could be an invalid integer or float is if it's a string.
  # If you're accepting strings in the first place, just cast all input as a
  # string and count the decimals it contains.
  value = '1.2.3'
  value.to_s.scan(/\./).count <= 1
  => false
  ```